# error while executing datadog-agent info command : instance #0 [ERROR]: 'Failed connection [Errno 61] Connection refused'

Tags: statsd, datadog

`statd.yaml` in `conf.d` is configured as follows

```
init_config:

instances:
  - host: localhost
    port: 8125
```

after starting Datadog-agent I get one error as shown below

everything else runs fine, Also in `datadog-conf` I have mentioned the forwarder's IP and API key as well, but it is not showing in host map in Datadog webUI

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the API key of Datadog changes everytime whenever in close the site and open a new instance. so after entering new API key , the issue was solved

[image]